# Capture errors of any type to variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to develop my own error handling system for a PowerShell script. I want to force two basic principles:

1. If ANY error is detected while the script is running - no ANY red text=error message on console.
2. In the same time, ANY error must be stored as text to it's own variable for further analysis.

I can't say I don't know what to do. For non-terminating errors I can, for example, use streams redirecting:

```
$e1=Write-Error "UUU" 2>&1
$e2=Get-Process none_null 2>&1
```

For terminating errors I can use try/catch:

```
try{7/0} catch{$e3=$_.Exception.Message}
```

What I don't know - is how to develop a UNIVERSAL code pattern, that will work equally with errors of any type. Pattern with redirecting(e1/e2) didn't work with terminating errors, try/catch didn't catch non-terminating errors.  My only idea right now is to set variable *$ErrorActionPreference* to value **Stop**. In other words - make ANY error as terminating type and then stick to try/catch pattern.

Is this the only way in my scenario? Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Hi @Smarty - Would you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38353532/edit) and try to clarify your #1 point in the question?  I can't seem to clarify what this means: `"no any red text=error message on console."`   Does this mean you DON'T want any red text?  Or, are you saying you want to print out a specific error, in PLACE OF the red text?  I tried to edit the question, but I couldn't figure out what you wanted for #1.

Comment: `$e = & {Write-Error Error;1/0} 2>&1`

Comment: Hi,@gravity!

>>Does this mean you DON'T want any red text?

Exactly. I DON'T need/want any red text on console(while my script is running), and it doesn't matter how severe error was detected. No-red-text. Never.

Comment: @PetSerAl - just magnificent,  exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`$Error`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx)?

> **`$Error`**
>   Contains an array of error objects that represent the most recent errors. The most recent error is the first error object in the array (`$Error[0]`).